# How do I solve $3^{\ln{2}} \times x^{\ln x + \ln 6 + 1} = \frac{3e^2}{4}$

Tags: logarithms

I've been going at this question for 2 hours, my teacher wants us to solve for x without a graphing calculator.

\begin{equation} 3^{\ln{2}} \times x^{\ln x + \ln 6 + 1} = \frac{3e^2}{4} \end{equation}

Comment: $\ln$ on both sides should give you a quadratic in $\ln x$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I get how I can solve using quadratics, except, I can't factor the quadratic.

Comment: Then use the quadratic formula...

Comment: Oh dear, this is about to get really tedious to punch into my calculator :P

Comment: @suchaHassle: solving the problem algebraically should mean that you leave it in expression form...

Comment: Stick with it, and repeatedly use the fact that $\ln 6 = \ln 2 + \ln 3$. The discriminant resolves into a pretty peachy $(3 + \ln 3 - \ln 2)^2$.

Comment: @abiessu my bad, I'm not thinking straight anymore

Comment: @stochasticboy321 so... apparently you don't even need the quadratic formula haha. The "constant" value is actually factorable! My friend showed me this: http://i.imgur.com/Zdh8MSR.jpg

Comment: Ah, that's nice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: isolate the $x$ term.

Hint 2: identify a quadratic in $\ln x$.

> $$(\ln x+\ln 6+1)\ln x = \ln 3+\ln e^2-\ln 4-\ln 3^{\ln 2}$$